# document.getElementById is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, getelementbyid

I have the following JavaScript working in IE, but not on Chrome and Firefox.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#applicationSelect').change(function() {
document.getElementById('dropdown').value = "APPLICATION";
});

});
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="dropdown" value="" />
```

When I look in Firebug, the code errs:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown") is null
document.getElementById('dropdown').value = "APPLICATION";
```

I need your advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't see element with 'dropdown' id.

Comment: Are you sure you have element with id "dropdown" in your html?

Comment: where have you declared a tag with ID `dropdown`??

Comment: Include your HTML for `#applicationSelect` and `#dropdown`.

Comment: Hi All, yes it way my typo error, it should be "dropdown" not "submitAs". Thanks.

Comment: sooooo... does that mean you fixed it?

Comment: @Aaron - No, look at the HTML. The `input` element doesn't have an `id`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `input` element doesn't have an `id`! Change `name` to `id`, or add an `id` too:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dropdown" id="dropdown" value="" />
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add an `id`, you could use `getElementsByName` (which [doesn't work very well](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) cross-browser), or you could use a jQuery attribute selector:

```
$("input[name='dropdown']").val("APPLICATION");
```

**Update**

I just noticed that you said in your question that it was working in IE. That means you must be using a pretty old version of IE, because `getElementById` in IE7 and below incorrectly selects elements by `name`, as well as `id`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery already, why not use it to set your input value:

```
$('#dropdown').val('APPLICATION');
```

And as others noted, your input's `id` was not 'dropdown'.

Also, note that to one may use `$` in place of `jQuery` in most use-cases.

Comment: @Jemru-Da: no problem :) jQuery is *very* useful, I'm sure you'll love working with it!

Comment: jQuery *is* very useful, but that doesn't mean it has to be used for even the simplest of tasks (like changing the value of an input). It's far, far quicker to use native DOM methods where possible.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: nor did I insist that he do so.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson - Not saying you did. Just pointing out the fact that sometimes people are too quick to settle on jQuery. Someone posted this link in a comment yesterday: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Haha, with a name like **I<3jQuery**, I would expect nothing less! I suggested he use jQuery in his case only because it was obvious he was already doing so. I'm not going to go around suggesting its use in trivial cases. Raw JS has its place as well, of course.